# configure tries to test-run a cross compiled program

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, autotools, configure

I try to compile something for IBM Blue Gene/Q with GCC 4.9. As a dependency I need the gmp (GNU Multi Precision) library, I use version 6.1.1. This comes with GNU Autotools.
Strangely, is has worked with LLVM before. And yesterday it did not work at noon but again in the evening and not any more today. I am thoroughly confused, honestly.

On Blue Gene/Q, you compile on an IBM PowerPC 740 and let it run on an IBM PowerPC A2 processor. Therefore you need to use the cross compiler. My `configure` is the following:

```
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/gmp-6.1.1/configure \
    --prefix=/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/local-juqueen \
    --host=powerpc64-bgq-linux \
    --build=powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    CC=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc \
    CXX=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpig++ \
    'CFLAGS=-O2 \
    -finline-limit=50000 \
    -Wall \
    -Wpedantic \
    -fmax-errors=1 \
    -fdiagnostics-color=auto \
    -Drestrict=__restrict__ \
    --std=gnu99'
```

## Error regarding CC_FOR_BUILD

The first issue has been this error.

```
/usr/include/stdio.h:34:21: error: stddef.h: No such file or directory
```

The generated `Makefile` has used `CC` for a few files but then called itself recurively using `CC=$(CC_FOR_BUILD)`. And that is just set to `cc` by default, the frontend compiler which does not do any good on the compute backend. So I have added `CC_FOR_BUILD=/bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc` to the `configure` flags. That fixed that error.

## Testing cross compiled binary

Then the `configure` script runs a bit further:

```
checking build system type... powerpc64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... powerpc64-bgq-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for powerpc64-bgq-linux-strip... no
checking for strip... strip
configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
checking ABI=mode64
checking whether /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc is gcc... yes
checking compiler /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc -O2 -finline-limit=50000 -Wall -Wpedantic -fmax-errors=1 -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Drestrict=__restrict__ --std=gnu99 ... yes
checking compiler /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc -O2 -finline-limit=50000 -Wall -Wpedantic -fmax-errors=1 -fdiagnostics-color=auto -Drestrict=__restrict__ --std=gnu99 has sizeof(long)==8... yes
checking for powerpc64-bgq-linux-gcc... /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc option to accept ISO Standard C... (cached) none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc -E
checking build system compiler /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc... no
configure: error: Specified CC_FOR_BUILD doesn't seem to work
```

Looking at `config.log`, it says

```
configure:9899: checking build system compiler /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc
configure:9912: /bgsys/local/gcc/4.9.3/bin/mpigcc conftest.c
configure:9915: $? = 0
/bgsys/source/srcV1R2M4.29840/comm/sys/buildtools/pami/common/bgq/BgqPersonality.h:102: 
/bgsys/source/srcV1R2M4.29840/comm/sys/buildtools/pami/common/bgq/BgqPersonality.h<102>
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/gmp-6.1.1/configure: line 10000: 26929 Aborted                 (core dumped) ./a.out
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/gmp-6.1.1/configure: line 9917: ./b.out: No such file or directory
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/gmp-6.1.1/configure: line 9917: ./a.exe: No such file or directory
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/gmp-6.1.1/configure: line 9917: ./a_out.exe: No such file or directory
/homec/hbn28/hbn28e/Sources/gmp-6.1.1/configure: line 9917: ./conftest: No such file or directory
configure:9922: result: no
configure:9927: error: Specified CC_FOR_BUILD doesn't seem to work
```

It seems to use the correct compiler. When running the program on the frontend (where I compile), it fails since the `BgqPersonality.h` has special information about the compute backend, the program just cannot run on the frontend.

`configure` assumes that the compiler is broken (which it arguably is for the *frontend*) and stops building. Previously I had neither error with LLVM, the cross compilation has just worked fine. `configure` even says `checking whether we are cross compiling... yes` so it must be aware of the situation. Perhaps the `CC_FOR_BUILD` is meant for the frontend whereas `CC` is for the compute backend. Without `CC_FOR_BUILD` I cannot compile as written above.

Is there some way to get this cross compiled properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CC_FOR_BUILD` is supposed to be a compiler that can compile tools for the *current* system, rather than the one you want to build the binaries for. The name comes from the fact that `CBUILD` is the name to reference the system the build happens on.

I [wrote a blog post some time ago](https://blog.flameeyes.eu/2009/01/the-canonical-target/) that explains the nomenclature of these systems and how they are supposed to be used.